# PHP Different shorthand if

Tags: php

After checking some shorthand if's i got confused.

```
$num = 10;
return ($num>0)? 'banned' : 'free';
```

and

```
$num = 10;
return ($num>0 ? 'banned' : 'free');
```

are both equal or the first one is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried/tested them? Same result? Different result?

Comment: @Rizier123 both works well, its annoying when i see different ways.

Comment: So they come down to the same.

Comment: There are always different ways young terrapin.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i prefer one life, one world, one language, one country, one way , one ... . that's kinda ridiculous.

Comment: If those are your preferences you will want to choose a different back-end language, but none will be perfect.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well, imma use the second one that looks handsome lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the case are true is their own state.

The first one

```
return ($num>0)? 'banned' : 'free';
```

is used when you need to compare two or more conditions as in

```
return ($num > 0 && $num <= 10) ? 'banned' : 'free'. ' model' ;
```

Here, **' model'** is applied to only false condition.

This can be applied into the second expression as well.
The brackets in second expression defined as one expression. as in

```
return ($num > 0 ? 'banned' : 'free' ) . ' model' ;
```

Here, **' model'** is concatenated to any of the result.

Its totally based on your priority of selecting the bracketss.